# Carousel padding on first item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with [owl carousel using stage padding](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/stagepadding.html).

I'm using the carousel with `loop:false`. I'm trying to get the first item to be without padding on left and that after slide it keeps the same padding for both items on left and right.

So at page load it should be like this:
[image]

And on slide:
[image]

Using stage-padding gives padding both left and right. Giving space on first item as shown in my [test](http://pixelbypixel.comli.com/owl/).

The problem is that if I remove the `padding-left` (to get the first item attached on left without margin) I get this result on slide:
[image]

Any idea how can I solve this?

This is my markup:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
</div>

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    stagePadding: 40,
    loop:false,
    margin:2,
    nav:false,
    items:2
})
```

Answer (score 2):

***Add This css it will be work fine..***

.owl-stage{padding-left:0px !important;}

Answer (score 1):

Its from inline style, try to find this line and remove `padding-left` like this:

```
<div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); 
transition: all 0s ease 0s; width: 11132px; 
padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 40px;">.. </div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. If I remove the `padding-left`  then on slide it doesn't shows the slide on the left. Just as the last image of the question.

Answer (score 1):

u can add "left" just like this:
`$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({ stagePadding: 40, loop:false, margin:2, nav:false, items:2, left: -30 })`

Answer (score 1):

you can this simple start in right use this code

```
.owl-stage {
    right: -32px;
 }
```

or start in left use this code simple

```
.owl-stage {
    left: -32px;
 }
```

you use tag style in your CSS on inline in your code

Comment: Applying left in negative works great. But, for the last item leaves blank space on right side